# how to understand javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple javascript code:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result = result * base;
  return result;
}

power(2, 10);
```

but it s hard for me to understand what is the relationship between for loope and the result in the for loop. Can anyone describe the process in here? I know that the answer is 1024 and that it is 2*2*2*2*2*2*...... but it is har for me to understand how for and result is related. result is always 1? Or somehow it grabs the updated version from the loop? Thank you!

Comment: Not JavaScript related. Basic knowledge of algorithms needed.

Comment: Your `power` function is flawed, because it doesn't do anything with the `exponent` argument. Try working on that.

Comment: Where does this code come from? The exponent parameter is not taken into account which seems obviously wrong + the numbers array is not useful and numbers.length should be replaced by exponent.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/loops

Comment: Wow.  Remind me to avoid codecademy.com

Comment: @user2400776    If you are trying to write the power function in javaScript, then your function is wrong and very ineffective. I am sure you can invoke the core java power function (cannot remember what it's called OTOMH)

Comment: @Richard: It's peer reviewed, you can try it out and leave feedback instead of avoiding it.

Comment: @hakre Aah, ok.  So this is just someone else's bad code, then.  I see.

Comment: There is no understanding necessary, a documented function that does the same [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow). Please don't ask for individual tutoring with a programming language here on SO. Also please understand that Stackoverflow is not a bug- or issue-tracker for third-party code.

Comment: @Richard: It could be also the users own code. The site has code-puzzles users need to fill out / extend for learning the very basics. Some kind of interactive tutorial. If it's really from code-academy, the user should use the forums there, they are specialized on the tutorials and the code therein they offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say I pass `power(2, 10)`. Here's how it's going to run, with each iteration:

```
i | result
--+-------
- | 1
0 | 1 * 2 = 2
1 | 2 * 2 = 4
2 | 4 * 2 = 8
.
.
.
9 | 512 * 2 = 1024
```

However, the `numbers` array is redundant. You'll need to check against `exponent` (`i < exponent`)

Comment: Ok, thanks! This has helped!

Comment: @user2400776: `base` always remains 2, since result get's overwritten on each iteration, it gets doubled by `base` multiple times, hence it gets from 1 to 2, from 2 to 4, and so on. The state of `result` is preserved between iteration.

Answer (score 2):

numbers is totally unnecessary. the length of the array [0....x] is x. So your for loop is really for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++). Hope that sorts it out. Also, you don't want to go to 10, but rather to exponent. Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
```

Comment: you screw up all of you code if you did ` i = 0; ` in your loop :O

Answer (score 2):

why do you not write this?

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    result = result * base;

  return result;
}
```

or there is also e javascript-integrated way

```
Math.pow(base, exponent);
```

Comment: Did you try this? Hint: when your exponent is one, how many times does the loop run?

Comment: i have less or equals to exponent


    i <= exponent

Comment: that means it loops 1 time

Comment: Try it. When your exponent is one, the loop runs twice (once when i = 0 and again when i = 1), which is wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/7gjmv/

Comment: you 're right :) i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

when you call a function with power(2,10) you give variable "base" value of 2, and then it multiplies the result (which is 1) by 2 for 10 times, I see no use of that second variable "exponent"